# Proving $S=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\mid x^2+y^2\le 4x, x^2+y^2\le 16-z,z\ge 0\}$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> I would like to show the set $$S=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\mid x^2+y^2\le 4x, x^2+y^2\le 16-z,z\ge 0\}$$ is compact.

I thought I should write down the set as

$$S=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\mid(x-2)^2+y^2\le4\right\}\cap\left\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\mid 
 x^2+y^2+z\le 16,z\ge 0\right\}$$
Then, define continuous functions $f,g:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$ as
$$f(x,y,z)=(x-2)^2+y^2\quad\text{ and }\quad g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z.$$

We need to find $f^{-1}([0,4])$ and $g^{-1}([0,16])$ ( because $z\ge 0\implies x^2+y^2+z\ge0$)

Both $[0,4]$ and $[0,16]$ are closed in $\Bbb R$ because their complements $(-\infty,0)\cup(4,+\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)\cup(16,+\infty)$ are open in $\Bbb R$.

Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, both $f^{-1}([0,4])$ and $g^{-1}([0,16])$ are closed in $\Bbb R^3$ and it follows their intersection $S=f^{-1}([0,4])\cap g^{-1}([0,16])$ is also closed in $\Bbb R^3.$

Now, I want to show $S=f^{-1}([0,4])\cap g^{-1}([0,16])$ is bounded, in other words, $\exists M>0,$ such that $f^{-1}([0,4])\cap g^{-1}([0,16])\subseteq\overline{B((0,0,0),M)}.$

As $S=f^{-1}([0,4])\cap g^{-1}([0,16])\subseteq g^{-1}([0,16]),$ if we prove $g^{-1}([0,16])$ is bounded, the same should hold for any of its subsets. Let's take an arbitrary $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3$ for which it holds $x^2+y^2+z\le 16$.

First, $x^2+y^2+z\le 16\quad\&\quad z\ge 0\implies x^2,y^2,z\le 16$.
Then, $0\le z\le 16\implies z^2\le 16^2,$ so
$$\|(x,y,z)\|_2\le M:=\sqrt{16+16+16^2}.$$

Therefore, $$S=f^{-1}([0,4])\cap g^{-1}([0,16])\subseteq g^{-1}([0,16])\subseteq\overline{B((0,0,0),M)}.$$

Finally, $S$ is closed and bounded in $\Bbb R^3,$ meaning it is compact.

Is my answer correct? Should I improve it?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is fine. An alternative proof can be done using cylindrical coordinates, then

$$
S=\{(r,\theta ,z)\in [0,\infty )\times [0,2\pi)\times \mathbb{R}:r\leqslant 4\cos \theta\,\land\, 0\leqslant z\leqslant 4-r \}
$$

Therefore for any chosen $(x,y,z)\in S$ we find that

$$
\|(x,y,z)\|_2^2=x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2+z^2\leqslant 16+16=32
$$

so $S$ is bounded. The closedness is easier to show using intersections of closed sets as you did.